# How to send tokens to a address with a specific contract?

Tags: tokens, ether, erc-20, myetherwallet, mycrypto

I want to send tokens from my wallet to a crypto-currency exchange website wallet with a specific contract used by the crypto currency exchange website. For example- I want to send token to this address 0x1d47b9fe35359cb8ba56d3570941bc94066cb0ef and contract is 0xd070e8D24743d19bb2Fb4d0b6f574A173B2bd06B. Please help.

Comment: Please, provide more details.  What do you know about address and contract you need to send tokens to? Does exchange provide any instructions?  Do not send tokens directly to the contract's address, because contract will not be able to react of the transfer.

Comment: I want to send token to this address 0x1d47b9fe35359cb8ba56d3570941bc94066cb0ef and contract is 0xd070e8D24743d19bb2Fb4d0b6f574A173B2bd06B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are always based on a specific contract - the token contract. A token is nothing more than a ledger in a regular smart contract. Especially if the token is an ERC20 token then all you need is to issue a transfer transaction to the token contract (you have to know its address). Many Ethereum wallets support ERC20 transfers directly so check your wallet for the needed functionality.

Comment: I want to send token to this address 0x1d47b9fe35359cb8ba56d3570941bc94066cb0ef and contract is 0xd070e8D24743d19bb2Fb4d0b6f574A173B2bd06B

Comment: Then issue a transfer transaction to the contract address where you specify how many tokens and give the receiver address. Check your wallet's instructions on how to do that.